# Why is IIS rewriting my URL query string to combine repeated keys?

Tags: iis-7.5, microstrategy

I'm working with MicroStrategy 10.3, hosted on IIS 7.5. I'm using their 
URL API to run a document, and change the value of a drop down selector.

IIS is tinkering with my query parameters though, via a 302 redirect. This URL:

`https://server/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx?Server=XXX&Project=XXX&evt=2048001&src=Main.aspx.2048001&maxWait=-1&documentID=XXX&evt=2048084&src=Main.aspx.oivm.rwb.2048084&ctlKey=XXX&elemList=hXX;XXX&evtorder=2048001%2c2048084&2048084=1&2048001=1`

is being 302'ed to:

`https://server/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx?Server=XXX&Project=XXX&evt=2048001%2C2048084&src=Main.aspx.2048001%2CMain.aspx.oivm.rwb.2048084&maxWait=-1&documentID=XXX&ctlKey=XXX&elemList=hXX%3BXXX&evtorder=2048001%2C2048084&2048084=1&2048001=1`

(The two distinct `evt` and `src` are being combined, and MicroStrategy is complaining that 'Event ID 2048001,2048084 is illegal'.)

Does IIS do this type of thing out of the box? It certainly *seems* unlikely. I can't see any custom HTTP redirects in IIS Manager for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS was most definitely not the culprit.

MicroStrategy was generating the 302 redirect itself, subsequent to an automated login. You would think that an enterprise application wouldn't rewrite its own URL such that it causes an error, but you'd be wrong.

I resolved the issue by manually adding a login event, and URL-encoding the two events I wanted to call into the target key:

`https://server/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx?Server=XXX&Project=XXX&evt=3054&src=Main.aspx.3054&target=evt%3D2048001%26src%3DMain.aspx.2048001%26maxWait%3D-1%26documentID%3DXXX%26evt%3D2048084%26src%3DMain.aspx.oivm.rwb.2048084%26ctlKey%3DXXX%26elemList%3DhXX%3BXXX%26evtorder%3D2048001%252c2048084%262048084%3D1%262048001%3D1`